# How to cancel BeforeEdit event in gxt EditorGrid based on data stored in model for the selected row

Tags: gxt

I have an EditorGrid. I would like to cancel the edit (using the BeforeEdit event) if the user does not have edit rights to that specific column. This data (a "canEdit" value), is in the data store for the row, but has not been added a column to the grid.

I think the best way to go about this is by cancelling the edit in the BeforeEdit event. I am having trouble, however, getting the data from the selected row in the BeforeEdit event. If someone could point me in the right direction with a small code snippet for how to grab data values from the selected row in a BeforeEdit event, I would be most appreciative! Or, if there is a better way to proceed, would love to hear from you.

Thank you!
Jennifer

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditorGrid<Plant> grid = new EditorGrid<Plant>(store, cm);        
grid.addListener(Events.BeforeEdit, new Listener<GridEvent<Plant>>(){

    @Override
        public void handleEvent(GridEvent<Plant> be) {
            //This retrieves the model being edited.
            Plant model = be.getModel();
            GWT.log("Model edited "+model.getName());           
        }           
});
```

This snippet uses the sample program provided by GXT. You can see the demo of the original sample as well the full code [here](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#editablegrid).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used that worked:

```
grid.addListener(Events.BeforeEdit, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
   @Override
   ModelData comment = ((EditorGrid)be.GetSource().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   Boolean canEdit = Boolean.parseBoolean(comment.get("canEdit").toString());
   be.setCancelled(!canEdit);
}
```